# What language is .NET Framework written in?

Tags: .net, c++, programming-languages

The question I always wanted to ask and was afraid to, actually - **what language is .NET Framework written in?** I mean library itself.
It seems to me that it was C and C++ mostly. (I hope Jon Skeet is reading this one, it`ll be very interesting to hear what he thinks about it)

Comment: Download the source and find out: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Comment: @michielvoo your link died, updated would be appreciated.

Comment: @Aelphaeis It's now just http://referencesource.microsoft.com

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The CLI/CLR is written in C/C++ and assembly.  Almost all of the .NET framework classes are written in C# > compiled to IL, which runs in the CLR.  If you crack open a framework library in Reflector, class, you may see an attribute such as [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)] which delegates the call to the CLI.

Comment: Please note that this only applies to Microsoft .NET. Other implementations of the CLI may be architected differently. E.g., in Mono a lot of the stuff that is written in C/C++ in Microsoft.NET is actually written in C# in Mono. Also, there are metacircular implementations, both by Microsoft Research and other organizations, that are written *entirely* in C#.

Comment: Jörg W Mittag - Thanks, didn't know that. Will have to take a look at the C# implementations.

Comment: This is basically stated in [StyleCop's History](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=A%20Brief%20History%20of%20CSharp%20Style), if anyone wants a reference cited.

Comment: What is "C/C++"? You can't even suggest that you meant "C and C++" this time, otherwise you'd have written "C/C++/assembly".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Going to be hard explaining an answer I wrote 5 years ago.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Which CLR implementations was written entirely in C#?

Comment: @bigown: Bartok, for example. Note, I did *not* say that there are CLR implementations written C#. The CLR is written in C++. However, the CLR is only one of many implementations of the CLI VES. There are other implementations of the CLI. Bartok is a static compiler from CIL to native code plus a runtime (including garbage collector), all written in C#. As such it is very much unlike the CLR (which is also a compiler but a dynamic JIT, not a static AOT), but it is still an implementation of the full CLI, including but not limited to CLI VES, CLI CIL, CLI libraries and so on.

Comment: Here's an archive.org link to the original reference: https://web.archive.org/web/20160126074657/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sourceanalysis/archive/2008/05/25/a-difference-of-style.aspx

Answer (score 6):

.NET was fully written in C and C++ because the base was in assembly language. Integration of assembly with C is much easier compared to newer languages.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft .NET Framework is divided in to many segments.

**CLR**: C++

**IO/Signal Processing**: Assembly

**Baseclass Library**: C#

**System.Threading**: C#

**Complex Data Structure**: C++

**Example**: GetHashCode

Answer (score 4):

There are parts of the .NET Framework that are open-source, like ASP.NET MVC, and it's written in C#.

Since the .NET Framework represents many assemblies, I'd presume that different libraries are written in different languages.  As long as the language is CLR-compliant, it can be used to build parts of the framework.

All said, though; I'd assume the lion's share of the .NET Framework is written in C++ and C#.

Answer (score -1):

**CLR / Compilers** - Visual C++

**Baseclass Library** - Simple Managed C (SMC)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2007/11/23/couple-of-historical-facts.aspx

Comment: From that article: "We actually wrote the original BCL in SMC.  It was a leap of faith to convert to C#".  So the .NET Framework BCL is actually C#