# in which language .net framework has been written?

Tags: .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What language is .NET Framework written in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324919/what-language-is-net-framework-written-in)

in which language .net framework has been written?

Answer (score 7):

The majority of the BCL is is written in C#.  It does rely on many native Win32 APIs via PInvoke.

The actual CLR is written in C++

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework consists of many components: the language compilers, the BCL, the CLR, ...
Some are written in unmanaged C++, other parts in managed .NET.