# In which language .Net base class library are written

Tags: c#, .net

When we say all c# libraries mainly built on .Net class library in which language class libraries are written ?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324919/what-language-is-net-framework-written-in will answer your question.

Comment: Presumably in C#, but the fact that you can't tell from the assembly means that whatever the answer is, it makes no difference.

Comment: I guess this should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324919/what-language-is-net-framework-written-in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can readily see this by obtaining the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx), it includes large amounts of original source code for the .NET Framework, comments included.  You'll see that all of the base classes were written in C#.

There is some C++/CLI as well, although it is not in the Reference Source.  Visible from the artifacts it leaves behind in the assemblies, particularly the internal `<Module>` class.  Present in mscorlib, System.Data and PresentationCore for example, the kind of assemblies that interop with native code.

The source code for the CLR, the C# compiler and the just-in-time compiler is available as well from the [SSCLI20 distribution](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917).  It is dated, accurate only for the .NET 2.0 release.  They were written in C++, a wee bit of assembly for very low-level functions that are processor specific.

Comment: The Reference Source link has been updated in the meantime to https://referencesource.microsoft.com.