# .Net with reference to R

Tags: .net, r

I'm really struggling to understand what the .net framework is or does, so I'd like to understand it with reference to the R programming language. Is it a "package" or collection of packages so to speak? Is it an IDE like R Studio? Can we make any comparisons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could think of it more like a collection of packages (it's a bit more than that, but let's keep things simple). These packages allow you to accomplish certain common tasks so that you can focus more on the other aspects of your program. The cool thing about .NET is that a variety of different languages can use the libraries, e.g., C#, Visual Basic, F#, etc., yet the libraries themselves only need to be implemented once. The compiler translates your code into a special language that is executed by the .NET runtime so that it can access the libraries. You can use whatever .NET language you like, but in the end, it looks pretty much the same to the computer once it gets compiled.

.NET is *not* an IDE. An example of an IDE would be Visual Studio or Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks @PowerSystemsDev. What language are the libraries written in? Is it just one language? Also, how is .net a bit more than a collection of packages?

Comment: According to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324919/what-language-is-net-framework-written-in), it's written in C/C++ and assembly.

Comment: By "a bit more," I was referring to the fact that your program executes in a virtual machine, similar to how Java works.