# C++: What operations are only possible by the use of pointers

Tags: pointers

I'm trying to understand the advantage of pointers. I know the definition and how to create one, but I still don't understand why they are powerful.

- So can someone give me an example of something that you can only do with pointers.
- I hear Python doesn't have pointers, does this mean that there are
  operations that can't be done using Python--I mean programming-wise, not just accessing a specific memory location and value? Examples?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome/5754#5754

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081519/why-does-c-use-pointers?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are primarily a mechanism to implement *reference semantics*. If you want to refer to an existing object that lives somewhere else, then you can do so by passing a pointer to that object around.

Without pointers, you could only pass *copies* of objects around. This would allow you to communicate *val­ues*, but you couldn't modify an *existing* object. (Unless your language offered native reference hand­ling, like C++ does, of course.)

As a test, imagine how you would implement the following code:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 20;

my_magic_swap(a, b);  // how to do this?!

assert(a == 20 && b == 10);
```

(The answer is of course that `my_magic_swap` should accept *pointers* (or equivalent) to the original variables.)